# Recruit gang members in Vice City

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-vice-city

How do I recruit gang members in GTA Vice City? I completed the game 100%, have 200 hp/armor and unlimited ammo already.

http://gta.wikia.com/Bodyguards

> Grand Theft Auto: Vice City In GTA Vice City, bodyguards only become
>   available to the player after receiving 100% Completion of the game.
>   The bodyguards can be found in the living room/bar of the Vercetti
>   Estate. The player can get a total of three bodyguards at one time.
>   In-game, the bodyguards are depicted as members of the Vercetti gang.

http://www.grandtheftwiki.com/Backup

> The Backup feature was first introduced in Grand Theft Auto: Vice
>   City, but to a minor extent. The player can only gain backup after
>   achieveing 100% completion of GTA Vice City. Once the player achieves
>   100% completion of the game, three Vercetti Gang members will spawn in
>   the TV room of the Vercetti Estate. The player can hire them by
>   walking into the halo next to them, but at the cost of $2000.

So, there are no people at all in the "living room"... I checked many times. What a let down...

Comment: To my recollection there is no way to do that in Vice City.

Comment: Numerous sites state that that's what you get when you get to 100%. Alas they were all written ages ago when only Ps2 and PC versions existed. I need hot fresh facts.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the feature is still there in Vice City for iOS. I don't know what happened but after running around randomly rampaging a few days and then returning to the mansion, the three promised gang members were waiting in the room to the right after entering the mansion. Maybe I got some higher criminal rating(?)

Answer (score -1):

If you saved at the mansion, you will need to run off the island, and then come back in order for them to spawn. They do not spawn on save.